# UITableView Scrolling stuck when content/text of TableCell is big

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, rss, lazy-loading

Am creating a Rss feed app. Where i need to show Description (more than 5000 characters each). Am able to show all feeds in my app but my problem when i try to scroll the UITableView the scrolling not smooth i believe i need to make lazy loading for my content but am new to iphone development. Can any one show me correct way. And also set correct Cell Size according to the content size.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";

    SimpleTableCell  *cell = (SimpleTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SimpleTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];


    }


    MWFeedItem *item = [itemsToDisplay objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if (item) {

        if(cell.gestureRecognizers.count==0){
            UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress=[[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longSelection:)];
            longPress.minimumPressDuration=1.0;
            [cell addGestureRecognizer:longPress];


        }

        UIImageView *imageView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];
        UIImage *image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Background.png"];

        imageView.image=image;
        cell.backgroundView=imageView;
        [[cell  textLabel] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

        cell.textLabel.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentRight;
        cell.textLabel.text=item.content;
        cell.textLabel.numberOfLines=0;
        cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0];
        [cell.textLabel sizeToFit];


        }

    return cell;



}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `-(CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

like so:

```
-(CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    MWFeedItem *item = [itemsToDisplay objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    //make sure to add the font you're using
    CGSize stringSize = [item.content sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:14]
                                     constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(320, MAXFLOAT)
                                         lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    int rowHeight = stringSize.height;

    return rowHeight;
}
```

Put this code:

```
    UIImageView *imageView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];
    UIImage *image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Background.png"];

    imageView.image=image;
    cell.backgroundView=imageView;
```

Inside of here like so and remove it from where it is now (keeping it there causes you to have new imageviews created every time you scroll:

```
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SimpleTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        UIImageView *imageView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];
        UIImage *image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Background.png"];

        imageView.image=image;
        cell.backgroundView=imageView;

    }
```

Comment: now height of the cell is ok but still UITableView Scrolling is not smooth since content is too big.

Comment: hi shabazco, i think scrolling not smooth because the content/Text is big. i think there is no problem with image. even if i remove the image still scrolling is not smooth, it taking small time to load new table cell with big content .